# Terraform AWS VCPe Route Creation Endpoint Not Found

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

When I create a route to an endpoint I get the following error:

`InvalidVpcEndpointId.NotFound: The vpcEndpoint ID 'vpce-044e0beXXXXXXXX' does not exist.`

But further up in the output (and on the console) I can see the endpoint is created:

`module.sec.aws_vpc_endpoint.s3[0]: Creation complete after 6s [id=vpce-044e0beXXXXXXXXX]`

This is what I have to create the route:

```
resource "aws_route" "s3_route" {
  count = length(var.s3_routes)

  route_table_id         = aws_route_table.main.id
  destination_cidr_block = var.s3_routes[count.index]
  vpc_endpoint_id        = var.s3_endpoint_ID[0]

}
```

This module is an example of one that calls it:

```
module "sec-route-NATGW-ifw-a" {

  source = "./route"
  depends_on = [module.i-dmz, module.t-dmz, module.cde, module.tgw-core, module.tgw-ifw]

  vpc_id = module.sec.vpc_id
  subnet_association = [for s in range(0, length(module.sec.natgw_subnet_IDs)) : module.sec.natgw_subnet_IDs[s] if module.sec.natgw_subnet_AZs[s] == "${local.region}a"]
  s3_endpoint_ID = module.sec.s3_endpoint_ID

  s3_routes = local.s3_ips      
}
```

And this is the output for the ID:

```
output "s3_endpoint_ID" {
  value = aws_vpc_endpoint.s3[*].id
  description = "ID for S3 Endpoint"
}
```

And the resource to create the endpoint:

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "s3" {
  count = var.s3_servicename == "" ? 0 : 1

  vpc_id       = aws_vpc.SEC.id
  service_name = var.s3_servicename
}
```

FYI VPCE ID has been changed from script.

Comment: We need a minimal reproducible example - plesae add more code to be able to reproduce this as we can't see the creation of your VPCE

Comment: How do you pass the value to the variable?

Comment: Hi @ErmiyaEskandary, I've attached more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the configuration on my route resource, I replaced it with the following:

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint_route_table_association" "s3" {
  count = length(var.s3_endpoint_ID) == 0 ? 0 : 1

  route_table_id = aws_route_table.main.id
  vpc_endpoint_id = tostring(var.s3_endpoint_ID[0])
}
```

I don't think the tostring() is needed and I changed how count worked slightly, but adding the destination_cidr_block argument was the issue.